# Getting error while connectiong to godadday mysql server

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, hosting, web-hosting

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Dbconnection" 
       connectionString="Server=1.1.1.1; Port =3306; Database=OnlineShopping; Uid=userID Pwd=password />
</connectionStrings>

String conStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"].ConnectionString;

MysqlConnection con = new MysqlConnection (conStr);
con.open();
```

> Error:
>
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTrace.LogError(Int32 id, String msg) at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver() at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection() at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() at
>   Admin_indx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Note : I am able to use Mysql server database(Database Located at my hosting site) from my local Computer it's work fine,
But When I try to use same from Live code it's giving me error.

Comment: You need to print out the actual error - all that says is it failed to open - whats the actual error message

Comment: Did you follow their instructions here? https://www.godaddy.com/help/connect-remotely-to-databases-4978 In particular _Free Web Hosting accounts cannot enable Direct Database Access._

Comment: I am using paid service of godadday, While I am connect remotely to databases its working but when publish same code on live it throws above Error

Answer (score 0):

Finally got answer,
We have to add ODBC Data Source on Godaddy.
In this we have to select over Database and Driver type ,
after this you can test your connection using your database USER ID and PASSWORD. You will get message Connection Established Successfully.

In Addition to that you have to change